# Hive query to find Which month is highest paid salary by Department

Tags: hiveql

my input

```
Department     Jan_sal      Feb_sal         Mar_sal

civil            1            5               5
mech             2            7               2
civil            3            8               9
mech             6            4               4
mech             5            6               6
Elec             4            5               3
mech             8            5               5
Elec             8            5               4
```

Expected output

```
Civil       Mar
Mech      Feb
Elec       Jan
```

Comment: (1) Why does a department has more than 1 record in the source table? (2) what is the logic going from the source table to the expected output?

Comment: Hi Dudu , thank for response,  i need highest salary paid month for each department? Actually they are more columns like employee , location, etc..

Comment: (1) Each department is located in different locations in a company.   (2) first we need to find the sum of each month based on department, then finally we need get highest month salary of each department.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, here are some

**Option 1: sort_array**

```
select    department
         ,sort_array
          (
              array
              (
                  struct(-sum(Jan_sal),'Jan')
                 ,struct(-sum(Feb_sal),'Feb')
                 ,struct(-sum(Mar_sal),'Mar')
              )
          )[0].col2

from      mytable

group by  department
```

**Option 2: posexplode + row_number**

```
select  department
       ,elt (i,'Jan','Feb','Mar)

from   (select    t.department
                 ,pe.pos+1 as i
                 ,row_number() over (order by sum(pe.val) desc) as rn

        from      mytable t
                  lateral view posexplode(array(Jan_sal,Feb_sal,Mar_sal)) pe

        group by  t.department
                 ,pe.pos
        ) t

where   rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi dudu, i got the below --> error Argument 1 of function SORT_ARRAY must be array<PRIMITIVE>, but array<struct<col1:bigint,col2:string>> was found.

Comment: hey sorry dudu, you code is correct but im getting error because i done some mistake so i posted it. so please help me out.

Comment: Hi Dudu, can you tell solution for this error    
Argument type mismatch ''mar_sal'': Argument 1 of function SORT_ARRAY must be array<PRIMITIVE>, but array<struct<col1:bigint,col2:string>> was found.

Comment: Might be a hive version issue (which one are you using?). Check the other solution.

Comment: I'm using cdh 4.7  , yes even i tried second query im getting error like FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'version' '<EOF>' '<EOF>'

Comment: The error doesn't make any sense. Verify what exactly you have executed. P.s. what Hive version are you using?